# Any routing API with OpenStreet Map Data that is reliable?

Tags: routes, openstreetmap

I am looking for a reliable API that uses OpenStreet Map Data for calculating routes, as I don't afford the Google/Bing minimum price license. Is there any such service, even if it has a subscription fee, but which is not that high (max $30/month).

YOURS seemed a good implementation, but unfortunately they don't have enough hardware to make the system reliable enough for a comercial application

Comment: Just like it's not allowed to embed map rendered by openstreetmap.org to your web, I don't think you would be allowed to use the routing. But you can get the software and run it on your own server.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not allowed to embed map rendered by openstreetmap.org to your web"? There are even examples of how to do it on their website. I though of using it in my admin panel. Can you please point me to this requirement? Thanks

Comment: It is allowed, but limited. The [language limiting it is rather vague](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy). Basically you are free to use it for something quick and small, but if you make commercial application and hope to grow big, they will probably block you when you exceed a handful of users.

Comment: Anyone know if [MapQuest Directions API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws) is based on OSM or not? They're using it for some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/). I think they have some online service that you could use for prototyping, but you'll probably have to run the code yourself if you want to use it for anything bigger.